# Bug in tutorial: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting keyword_end

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am sorry for asking what may be a remedial question, but in learning rails i was trying to follow along note for note in this tutorial:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#configuration-gotchas

I am fie to section 5.7 - showing the results of the post, as instructed I add this line to routes.rb

```
post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)      posts#show
```

and the show method in posts_controller.rb:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.new (post_params)
    @post.save
    redirect_to @post
  end

  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  private
    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:title, :text)
    end

end
```

my routes.rb file is

```
Listing::Application.routes.draw do
  get "welcome/index"

  post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)  posts#show


  resources :posts


  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
  root 'welcome#index'
end
```

Here is the error:

> C:/Ruby-Projects/listing/config/routes.rb:4: syntax error, unexpected
>   ':', expecting keyword_end post GET /posts/:id(.:format) posts#show ^
>
> Rails.root: C:/Ruby-Projects/listing
>
> Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace This error occurred
>   while loading the following files:
>   C:/Ruby-Projects/listing/config/routes.rb

I am running rails 4.0, ruby 2.0 on 64 bit windows 8.

Admittedly I don't know what that line in the routes.rb is trying to do, but my goal was to type this in and pickup what i can, before digging into the subject full bore.  i cut and pasted the line, typed it in, and tried changing a couple of things - without results.

I am tired, and feeling stupid, so I am here asking for your help.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Good question! I had this same problem, and I think your question is the only one in search space that addresses it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That line in section 5.7 is just showing you the output of `rake routes`, it's not meant to be in your config/routes.rb file.

The line `resources :posts` in routes.rb generates the show posts route for you, test it by removing the line: `post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)      posts#show` and then running `rake routes` on the command line.

Comment: Thank you.I am new to this, and for  the life of me thought they wanted me to add that in routes.  It should make following the remainder of  the tutorial easier.  I will accept after the deadline passes.

Comment: No worries, I read through that tutorial and it's pretty unclear where that line came from and what you're supposed to do with it!

Comment: Where is that line supposed to be?
UPDATE: I see... it's supposed to be from the output of rake routes

Comment: I don't understand why it would show the output of rake routes? What does that have to do with submitting the form?

Comment: The tutorial is showing the output of `rake routes` in order to demonstrate that the show route exists, and that you need to create a corresponding action for the route in your controller. Submitting the form tries to redirect to the show action (`redirect_to @post`)

Answer (score 2):

i'm new to the ruby world i have started learning it this afternoon :)

i had the same error as yours and i solved it by changing the way routes have been written to the suggested style within the routes.rb file.

instead of what have been written on that tutorials copy and past this into your routes.rb

```
Blog::Application.routes.draw do
  get "welcome/index"
 resources :posts
   root 'welcome#index'
  get    '/posts/:id(.:format)'  =>   'posts#show'
 get    '/posts(.:format)'       =>   'posts#index'
end
```

save and check your posts url as suggested on that tutorials

```
http://localhost:3000/posts
```

it should work for you.

Comment: You don't actually need those last two lines in your `routes.rb` file, because the line `resources :posts` generates all 7 routes for you: index, new, create, show, edit, update and destroy